# CsvHelper try to export in csv a list which contain another list .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, csvhelper

I implement a web api in .Net Framework using csvHelper to export a csv.

I have the  classes

```
public class StudentInfo
{
    public Student Student {get;set;}
    public Courses[] Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
   public string CourseId {get;set;}
   public string CourseName{ get; set; }
}
```

I have a method which return a List

```
public List<StudentInfo> FetchStudentInfo()
{
    //bla bla 
}
```

Now I want to export in a csv the List using the csvHelper

here is my code

```
List<StudentInfo> records = _service.FetchStudentInfo()
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
    {
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(sw))
        {        
            csv.WriteRecords(records);
            sw.Flush();
        }
    }
```

but this code export to csv only the object Students.
How can export to csv for each student to have the list with the courses in the same line?

**For example 12 jim java c# python**

if i try

```
foreach(var item in records)
{
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(item.Student);//I have compile error because it want to pass an IEnumerable
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(item.Courses);
}
```

Comment: CSV files store rows of data, with each column separated by a comma delimiter. They can therefore only represent one entity type. If you want to nest types (Courses in Students), the you need to serialize to a different format. The obvious choice would be JSON (Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json).

Comment: I'd suggest using JSON or XML to serialize to, cause both allow more complex structures than CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dimmits answer works just fine and is easy to read.  I thought I would provide another option that is more configuration based.  It does require a modification to the `StudentInfo` class.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var studentInfos = FetchStudentInfo();

        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out))
        {
            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<StudentInfoMap>();

            csv.WriteRecords(studentInfos);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static List<StudentInfo> FetchStudentInfo()
    {
        Course[] courses1 = { new Course { CourseId = "1", CourseName = "java" }, new Course { CourseId = "2", CourseName = "c#" }, new Course { CourseId = "3", CourseName = "python" } };
        Course[] courses2 = { new Course { CourseId = "1", CourseName = "java" }, new Course { CourseId = "2", CourseName = "c#" } };
        return new List<StudentInfo>
        {
            new StudentInfo{ Student = new Student{Id = "12", Name = "Jim"}, Courses = courses1 },
            new StudentInfo{ Student = new Student{Id = "45", Name = "Dave"}, Courses = courses2 }
        };
    }
}

public class StudentInfoMap : ClassMap<StudentInfo>
{
    public StudentInfoMap()
    {
        References<StudentMap>(m => m.Student);
        Map(m => m.CourseNames).Index(3);
    }
}

public class StudentMap : ClassMap<Student>
{
    public StudentMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.Name);
    }
}

public class StudentInfo
{
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public Course[] Courses { get; set; }
    public string[] CourseNames { get { return Courses.Select(c => c.CourseName).ToArray(); } }
}

public class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public string CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much David i accept your comment as solution.It is very good approach!

Answer (score 0):

CSV format cannot represent a list in a list. I didn't figure how the data can be interpreted when reading the CSV after export.

XML or JSON must be prefer to export complex data into a flat file.

If you really want to get as a CSV file, you must use 2 different separator to distinct the 2 class (by example: the ',' for StudentInfo and ';' for the courses).

After I will create a class for represent CSV data:

```
public class StudentInfoCsv
{
    public Student Student {get;set;}
    public string Courses { get; set; }
}

List<StudentInfoCsv> csvData = new List<StudentInfoCsv>
foreach(var item in records)
{
    StudentInfoCsv.Add(new StudentInfoCsv()
    {
        Student = item.Student,
        Courses = CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv(item.Courses)
    }
}
csvWriter.WriteRecords(csvData);
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is

```
                       foreach (StudentInfo item in records)
                        {
                            csvWriter.WriteField(item.Student.Id);
                            csvWriter.WriteField(item.Student.Name);

                            foreach (var row in item.Courses)
                            {
                                csvWriter.WriteField(row.CourseName);
                            }
                            csvWriter.NextRecord();
                        }
```

and the output will be

> 12 jim java c# python